# What kind of functions whose integrals vanish on the unit disk?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $D:=\{ (x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n}) \in \Bbb R^{n} \mid 
x_{1}^{2}+ \cdots +x_{n}^{2} \leq 1 \}\ (n \in \Bbb N)$, 
and $f(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n})$ be a continuous real-valued
function on $D$.
Describe what kind of $f(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n})$ satisfies
the following equality
$$
\int \cdots \int_{D} f(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n})^{2}
dx_{1} \cdots dx_{n}=0.
$$
I don't know where to get started. Perhaps, [Green's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities) will play some role?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So we conclude that $f=0$ on $D$? That means this problem is true for more general domains rather than the unit disk?

Comment: Oh, I see. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer? I'd like to leave posts answered after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sketch of a proof:** If $f$ were positive at some point in $D$ then, by continuity, it would be positive on a neighborhood of the point -- and its square would be strictly positive on this neighborhood. If $f$ were negative at some point in $D$ then, by continuity, it would be negative on a neighborhood of the point -- and its square would be strictly positive on this neighborhood. Thus there can't be any nonzero points on the disk or else the integral would be nonzero (positive, in fact).  Thus $f = 0$ everywhere on the disk.